# Instruments Allocations of the charts using sprite kit template

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, instruments

I'm trying to understand how Instruments works and to make my apps better. Below is an image of the result for default SpriteKit Template. I don't understand why are so many Allocations, because the code is small

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5
            sprite.position = location

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

            sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            self.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }
```

[image: Result]

---

I try to find tutorials but many of them are very old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we aren't apple programmers, we don't really know what's going on inside SpriteKit.

I'm guessing it's just because of the complexity of the physics engine.

I suggest just watching out for leaks.